# How to use Application.OnTime to call a macro at a set time everyday, without having to close workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

I have written a macro that uses Application.OnTime that works if I manually execute the macro. I'm trying to automate this process so I don't have to write Application.OnTime in "This Workbook" or (Private Sub Workbook_Open() Most of you do this because you can have windows scheduler open the workbook at a certain time which starts the macros on open. I CANNOT USE SCHEDULER.

Because I am not able to use windows scheduler I will keep the workbook open and the timer should refresh my data then Call "my Macro" at a certain time everyday.

Where do I place this code, and how do I set an auto timer?

Comment: to be sure- you will keep Excel application open all the time? is there any constant time interval between each macro call? can you start it manually for the first time?

Comment: The workbook will be open all the time, never closing.  Interval will be the same.  (at 3:30 everyday)     if I were to start it manually one time at 3:30 is there a way for it to keep calling the macro everyday...24 hours later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a kind of recurrence procedure. It could look as follows:

```
Sub Call_At_3_30()
    'first call appropriate procedure 
    Call myProcedure
    'next, set new calling time
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("3:30:00"), "Call_At_3_30"
End Sub
```

Somewhere you will keep your main procedure, it this situation:

```
Sub myProcedure
    'your code here
End Sub
```

In this situation you need to run first subroutine `Call_At_3_30` only once. But you need to remember that Excel must be turned on all the time.

Optionally, if you want to call your procedure after 24 hours you could change `.OnTime` instruction in this way:

```
Application.OnTime Now + 1, "Call_At_3_30"
```

Some other modifications are possible, too.

Comment: This works perfect. I added the code from above and the macro executes perfectly but   but I'm getting the error message   Cannot run the macro                                                  Code: Sub Call_At_9_43()
    'first call appropriate procedure
    Call Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body
    'next, set new calling time
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("9:49:00"), "Call_At_9_49"
End Sub   I know my "sub call" doesn't match, but that shouldn't be an issue.  Will this popup error prevent it from running tomorrow at  9:49 if I don't click ok.   I'm thinking another call with send.keys to hit enter

Comment: I would need to see the complete code... (you could edit your question). `Cannot run the macro` suggest that you put wrong name of the calling sub. Error occurs during `Sub Call_at_9_43()` execution or after, as a result of `Application.OnTime`?

Comment: You are correct, to test that theory, just now I wrote this.  #1= no error  #2= error message       Sub Call_At_10_00()

End Sub
    'first call appropriate procedure
    Call Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body
    'next, set new calling time
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "Call_At_10_00"
     
Sub Call_At_9_43()
    Call Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:01:00"), "Call_At_10_49"
End Sub

Comment: to be clear this is correct     Sub Call_At_10_00() End Sub 'first call appropriate procedure Call Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body 'next, set new calling time Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "Call_At_10_00"      I hope it runs tomorrow.