# How do I change the value of a cell at a specific time in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, time

I am trying to change the value of cell **B1** to "`FALSE`" after 1:00 PM.
This is not working.

```
Sub MacroTimer()
    If Hour(Now) > 13 Then [B1].Value = "FALSE"
        ' Procedure to run timer sub.
        Module1.MacroTest
        ' Set last refresh time.
        [E1].Value = Time
        ' If cell B1 timer is true, run Macro again.
        If [B1].Value = "True" Then
            SetNextExecution
        Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: You have to use [Application.OnTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301512/how-to-use-application-ontime-to-call-a-macro-at-a-set-time-everyday-without-ha)

Comment: dumb question: why not directly put in the cell: `=IF(HOUR(NOW())>=13,"FALSE","TRUE")`?

Comment: You're overcomplicating it..

Comment: @DirkReichel couldn't you just simplify it to `=HOUR(NOW())<=13`

Comment: @ScottCraner yes and no... asuming he has a german client `=HOUR(NOW())<=13` would print `WAHR` and `FALSCH` but he may need `TRUE` and `FALSE`... having `...[B1].Value = "FALSE"` shows that he doesn't want `...[B1].Value = False`...

Comment: I did try putting =IF(HOUR(NOW())>=13,"FALSE","TRUE" in the cell, but the value of B1 determines if my next macro will run. See- If [B.1].Value = "true" Then SetNextExecution. If the value of B1 is a formula, it doesn't work. Basically, if B1 is "true" then the next set of macros will loop every 5 minutes.At 1PM I want B1 to change to "False", which will stop the loop and exit the sub. You are correct @DirkReichel this is global so it must remain English.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative macro solution:

```
Sub ctrl()
    If Format(Hour(Now), "ss:dd") > Format("23:00", "ss:dd") Then
        [B1].Value = "FALSE"
    Else
        [B1].Value = "TRUE"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really not sure but I think 23:00 is not 1:00PM.