# How to set a timer in a UserForm Textbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works perfectly but I have to click on the command button to activate it.

What I want is for the timer to run automaticaly when I open the workboox/UserForm.

When the timer reach 0 seconds, I want the workbook to automatically close using

```
Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Save
Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Close
```

This is the code that works with a commmand button:

In a module:

```
Public Const AllowedTime As Double = 1
```

In the Userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim userClickedPause As Boolean ' Gets set to True by the Pause button

Dim stopTime As Date

    userClickedPause = False
    ' If AllowedTime is the number of minutes with a decimal part:
    stopTime = DateAdd("s", Int(AllowedTime * 600), Now) ' add seconds to current time

    ' If AllowedTime is the number of seconds:
    'stopTime = DateAdd("s", AllowedTime, Now) ' add seconds to current time
    Do
        With UserForm1.TextBox1
            .Value = Format(stopTime - Now, "Nn:Ss")
        End With
        DoEvents
        If userClickedPause = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until Now >= stopTime


End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    userClickedPause = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid referring to `UserForm1` in the code-behind of `UserForm1`: that will not work as you expect, the minute you start `New`-ing up your forms. Use `Me` to refer to the *current instance* of the form. That said [this code might interest you](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/229656/23788)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thank you for your reply. I took a look at your link, but as a not so experienced vba user, I don't know where to look and what to understand. This link isn't much of help to me.

Comment: You need to learn to walk before you can run then. There are much easier ways to learn some VBA than dealing with timers and asynchronous callbacks. This busy-looping is hijacking the form's own message loop, ...everything is holding on a house of cards.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon If I had the choice, Id take it more easy and indeed learn to walk before I can run... but it's for work. I need to be able to time the userform for the users because they often forget the workbook opened, making it impossible for other users to use the Userform.

Comment: See [this Analyst Cave article](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-application-ontime/) (I've no affiliation).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Merci Mathieu!

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how you're showing the form. If you have this:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Then the form is modal, the default instance is shown, and you could handle the `Activate` event to execute code as soon as the dialog becomes active.

If you have this:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

Then the form isn't modal, and the `Activate` event will be a problem, because the timer will then re-initialize whenever the user clicks on the form after deactivating it by clicking somewhere else on the screen.

If you have this:

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show
End With
```

Then the `TextBox1.Text` property isn't being assigned on the instance that's being shown, and the box remains empty. However with that we now fully control when the form object gets created and destroyed, and now we can handle the `Initialize` event (fired once per instance, when the object is first created) because we *know* that the form object has just been created... but then, the form won't ever be shown, because the only available thread is busy with that `Do...Loop`, and while it allows the dialog's message pump to pump events (thanks to `DoEvents`), if the form isn't shown by the time that loop is entered, then no other code gets to run - so, firing that loop in an `Initialize` handler would be a very bad idea.

Consider looking into leveraging [`Application.OnTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) to schedule the execution of a procedure: what you want to do, is to say "invoke `DoStuff` in 1 second", and then resume executing whatever - not busy-looping, rather letting the form's message loop do its job. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17302474/1188513) for one of many examples.

Comment: Since the timer display might be a little tricky for my limited knowledge. Can you please help me on how to automatically close the workbook using `Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Close` and `Application.OnTime`

Comment: Does your macro open this `OUTIL_CRN.xlsm` file? If so then you should have a reference to the `Workbook` object returned by `Workbooks.Open`; store that reference in a module-level variable, and then your `OnTime` callback can use it. Make sure you're in a standard module (not a worksheet or ThisWorkbook module), see how it goes =)

Comment: `
Public Sub fermeoutil()
Workbooks("OUTIL_CRN.xlsm").Close
Call test
End Sub

Sub test()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "fermeoutil"

End Sub
`
not working ...

Comment: Is that code in a standard module (e.g. `Module1`)? That said I don't understand why you would want to close a workbook every 10 seconds... you'll need to handle the error that will be raised when `Workbooks("...")` can't find the workbook 10 seconds after you first closed it. Does "not working" stand for "subscript out of range" error 9?

Comment: I dont want it to close every 10 seconds. I'm just trying it out. Yes, it is in a module (module1). Not working stands for nothing happening at all at 10 seconds mark!